# how to pass a array of strings to request body [put request] in json format

Tags: http, go, command-line-interface

```
var tagsInput string

tagsInput = inputLine("Project tags [domain/topics etc, seprated by commas in input] :\n")

tags := strings.Split(tagsInput, ",")
parseTags, _ := json.Marshal(tags)
fmt.Println(tags)
fmt.Println(string(parseTags))
postBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
    "name":   name,
    "desc":   desc,
    "status": status,
    "tags":   string(parseTags),
})
```

[image: this is the request]

I need a array as the the tags like ["golang"]
but instead its a string .

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: What is your question? What help do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently trying to json marshal a map of strings `map[string]string`. What you want to do for the `tags` field is marshal an array of strings `[]string`.

The answer to your question is to marshal the `tags` variable only once. The quick solution is to make your map a map of type `interface{}`. It allows you to store arbitrary types in your map, which will be correctly json marshaled:

https://play.golang.org/p/7D-wy7rQ8o_6

```
    input := "golang, elixir, python, java"
    tags := strings.Split(input, ",")
    
    postBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
        "name":   name,
        "desc":   desc,
        "status": status,
        "tags":   tags,
    })
```

The downside is you lose your type safety. Now each field can be anything. A better approach is to create a data structure for this request:

https://play.golang.org/p/wTbrXH0HXoG

```golang
type Request struct {
    Name        string   `json:"name"`
    Description string   `json:"description"`
    Status      string   `json:"status"`
    Tags        []string `json:"tags"`
}

input := "golang, elixir, python, java"
tags := strings.Split(input, ",")

postBody, _ := json.Marshal(Request{
    Name:        name,
    Description: desc,
    Status:      status,
    Tags:        tags,
})
```

Comment: thank you so much for such a clear answer

Comment: Glad it was helpful